# How to activate linux-containers for docker in AppVeyor?

Tags: docker, appveyor, linux-containers

I want to use AppVeyor for the CI, and I want to use Linux containers for the docker. I use `Visual Studio 2017` image. When I ran `docker-switch-linux` I get the following error:

```bsh
Unable to start: The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: 'MobyLinuxVM' failed to start.
Failed to start the virtual machine 'MobyLinuxVM' because one of the Hyper-V components is not running.
'MobyLinuxVM' failed to start. (Virtual machine ID C5FFC9C0-7293-45A6-B7C6-3FFC31AE0D25)
The Virtual Machine Management Service failed to start the virtual machine 'MobyLinuxVM' because one of the Hyper-V components is not running (Virtual machine ID C5FFC9C0-7293-45A6-B7C6-3FFC31AE0D25).
at Start-MobyLinuxVM, <No file>: line 300
at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 395
```

Any clue?

I have also added `- ps: Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All` but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We stopped running Docker CE on `Visual Studio 2017` image because of issues with latest Docker CE and latest Windows Server 2016 updates we hit.

As a workaround, for Docker CE we provide image called `Windows Server 2019`. Sample usage is [here](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/appveyor-tests/win2k19-azure/builds/24580220). Note that we provide this image by request and need your AppVeyor account name for this. Please request access to this image by email to support@appveyor.com or by post to https://help.appveyor.com/.

Also we plan to add Containers feature (Docker EE) to generally available image `Visual Studio 2019`. Please watch [this](https://github.com/appveyor/ci/issues/3075) GitHub issue.

Comment: I saw samples on the usage but I was unable to use `Windows Server 2019` image, and I did not know I could request access to that image. Is there any special matters I should mention inside email?

Comment: Nothing special, just AppVeyor account. Or URL to your project. You can post it here as well if you are OK for it to be visible on public forum.

Comment: here is the appveyor url to my project: https://ci.appveyor.com/project/shahabganji/cli

Comment: OK, `Windows Server 2019` image is enabled for you.